# Registro Duplicado

Tags: ireport, jaspersoft-studio

Estou iniciando estudo na plataforma JasperSoft Studio antigo iReports e estou com problema na criação da query t-sql sair duplicado.

Tenho essa query:

```sql
SELECT 
    F2_CLIENTE,
    F2_LOJA,
    A1_NOME,
    A1_CGC,
    A1_INSCR,
    F2_DOC,
    F2_SERIE,
    F2_PLIQUI,
    F2_PBRUTO,
    D2_ITEM,
    D2_COD,
    D2_QUANT,
    B1_DESC,
    D2_LOCAL,
    B1_POSIPI,
    C6_PEDCLI,
    C6_ITEMCLI,
    C6_NUM,
    D2_PEDIDO,
    C6_ITEM,
    D2_ITEMPV,
    D2_DOC,
    C6_NOTA
FROM dbo.SF2010 AS SF2 
INNER JOIN dbo.SD2010 AS SD2
    ON SF2.F2_DOC = SD2.D2_DOC 
        AND SF2.F2_SERIE = SD2.D2_SERIE 
        AND SF2.F2_CLIENTE = SD2.D2_CLIENTE 
        AND SF2.F2_LOJA = SD2.D2_LOJA
INNER JOIN dbo.SB1010 AS SB1 
    ON SD2.D2_COD = SB1.B1_COD
        AND SD2.D2_LOJA = SB1.B1_LOCPAD
INNER JOIN dbo.SA1010 AS SA1 
    ON SF2.F2_CLIENTE = SA1.A1_COD 
        AND SF2.F2_LOJA = SA1.A1_LOJA
INNER JOIN dbo.SC6010 AS SC6 
    ON SD2.D2_PEDIDO = SC6.C6_NUM 
        AND SD2.D2_ITEMPV = SC6.C6_ITEM 
        AND SD2.D2_DOC = SC6.C6_NOTA 
        AND SD2.D2_SERIE = SC6.C6_SERIE
WHERE 
    F2_DOC = '000015051' AND F2_SERIE ='2'
    AND SF2.D_E_L_E_T_ != '*' 
    AND SD2.D_E_L_E_T_ != '*' 
    AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_ != '*' 
    AND SA1.D_E_L_E_T_ != '*' 
    AND SC6.D_E_L_E_T_ != '*'
ORDER BY SF2.F2_DOC
```

No banco de dados retorno somente um registro no Jasper Studio retorna três registro duplicados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Consulta mas simples duplica linha no jaspersoft studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]